# Trying to reference a variable out of a Json git ignored file

Tags: node.js, json

I have a file containing api sensitive keys. It is on git ignore, so I want to reference it out to a variable in order to use it's variables.

I have seen multiple questions about this issue but nothing solved my issue.

I have tried the following method which did not work -

[image]

I am getting the following error -

[image]

The JSON file is located at the same folder as the "module_fcm" is located, so I really am clueless about what could I have caused this error.

edit -

here is my directory -

[image]

and here is my file - (information is censored of course)

[image]

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of the directory, and a snapshot of the contents of the json file?

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury added

Comment: It looks like your cloudinary-account.json file is not saved. Probably it was empty, and then you added data, and forgot to save? Can you save and re-run the script?

Comment: Also, why are you using readFileSync instead of require?

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury the file is saved for sure. about the other solution you offered - can you please write how the code should be like? I really have no idea why am I using readFileSync instead of require, I just ran upon a possible solution for this issue and tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `module_fcm.js` file:

```
let jsonInput = require("./cloudinary-account.json");
console.log(jsonInput);
```